# How do I reference all non empty cells in a column (ex: all non empty cells below A1)

Tags: excel

How do I reference all non empty cells in a column (ex: all non empty cells below A1).

I have multiple sheets that have the same header but the data is of variable length on column one.

Let say each sheet will have the data on column C below C1 which is always non blank

I need to automatically get these copied in another spreadsheet that I manually point to this data sheet.

Ex: I work on Sheet1 , my data is in Sheet2 column C, C1 and the below, variable number of non blank cells

How do I copy automatically all data in Sheet2 from Sheet1.

Comment: Filter out blanks and copy visible cells? There are good examples on SO of how to do this. Or if you're just trying to find the last row, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in `Sheet2` column **C:C** like:

[image]

In `Sheet1` cell **E1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(Sheet2!C:C<>""), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]